# Couldn't open tensorboard with localhost?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I use a google instance to train my model. 
I want to check the performance via tensorboard
I ran : `tensorboard --logdir ./data/log` and got : `TensorBoard 2.1.1 at http://localhost:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`

But trying to access http://localhost:6006/ in chorme, it doesnt work ( This site can’t be reached )

**NOTE** : I'm running this in google server instance and want to access it on my local chorme.

Comment: Are you running on Google Cloud or Google Colab?

Comment: Google cloud ...